# mailto attribute not working in github web hosting

Tags: html, forms, github, form-submit, web-hosting

No action is happening when clicking the send button on my phone, i was using Chrome.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <form action="mailto:akuroy24@yahoo.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail:<br>
<input type="text" name="mail"><br>
Comment:<br>
<input type="text" name="comment" size="50"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

[webpage link](https://ankush-roy-007.github.io/trialhtml/)

Thank you for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use mailto with forms. You use it like this:

`<a href="mailto:name@email.com?subject=&cc=&bcc=&body=">Link text</a>`

Comment: Then how can i transfer all my form data in text field to my mail compose section?

Comment: In one of the videos i saw that by doing this, it automatically opens the compose section of mail with the value typed, which is mentioned in the text field.

eg.
name-xyz
comment-thankyou for helping

Comment: <https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_mail> please refer this, i pasted the same code.